# Django- Stuck and cannot get data to display on webpage

Tags: python, django

Here’s my issue. I can display data from one of my other tables (the stats table that I don’t show here) on my stats page and home page. That was the first time I was able to get it to work, (I am new to Django). Then I made another table in my database (the Alstandings table) and I made an app for that was well because I want a standings page. For some reason I cant get the data from my Alstandings table to display on the standings page. As far as I know I thought I replicated the process but maybe I’m missing something I don’t know about.  Yes, I have registered the app in my settings. I’m not getting any errors right now. Please, if anybody has valuable input on how to get this to work, please respond. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

**Standings/models**

```
from django.db import models


class Alstandings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    team = models.CharField(db_column='TEAM', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    w = models.IntegerField(db_column='W', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    l = models.IntegerField(db_column='L', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pct = models.DecimalField(db_column='PCT', max_digits=4, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gb = models.DecimalField(db_column='GB', max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rs = models.IntegerField(db_column='RS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ra = models.IntegerField(db_column='RA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    diff = models.IntegerField(db_column='DIFF', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    home = models.CharField(db_column='HOME', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    road = models.CharField(db_column='ROAD', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    east = models.CharField(db_column='EAST', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cent = models.CharField(db_column='CENT', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    west = models.CharField(db_column='WEST', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    l10 = models.CharField(db_column='L10', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    strk = models.CharField(db_column='STRK', max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'AlStandings'
```

**standings/index.html**

```
{% extends 'layout/layout.html' %}


{% block content %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>
    {% for index in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ index.team }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

**standings/urls**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
]
```

**standings/views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from standings.models import Alstandings



def index(request):
    data = Alstandings.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'standings/index.html', {"data": data})
```

**baseball/urls.py** (basically same as mysite/urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from baseball import views as baseball_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', baseball_views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^standings/', include('standings.urls')),
    url(r'^stats/', include('stats.urls')),
]
```

**baseball/views.py**    (basically same as mysite/views) I was able to get this view to work

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from stats.models import MlbFielder


def index(request):
    data = MlbFielder.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {"data": data})
```

Comment: What URL are you going to, and what do you actually see?

Comment: Urls is 127.0.0.1:8000/standings/   I see my bootstrap loaded in and my table header that says Team. I typed that in. It didn't come from my database. Rest of the page is blank.

Comment: Change `TemplateResponse` to the `render` shortcut and it should work.

Comment: How would that work. I have django.shortcuts import render up top. that's fine right? I need to change it in the view then, correct?

Comment: Add `print(data)` to the view to make sure that the queryset isn't empty. Does your `'layout/layout.html'` template contain a `{% content %}` block?

Comment: @NickT you have to put the "print(data)" statement _before_ you return (else it will never be executed).

Comment: Ater I refresh the page, in the terminal, it shows <QuerySet []>. I assume that means the queryset is empty? Where do I go from here?